# How do I check RVM version from inside Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rvm, environment-variables

I need to check the RVM version before taking action.  It seems like a straightforward question, but I had difficultly finding a list of RVM related variables available within a plain old Ruby app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RVM version information is stored in the shell's environment variables.  You can access rvm_version from Ruby like so:

```
puts "RVM version is #{ENV['rvm_version']}"
```